# how to install mongodb binary package on linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, installation, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to install mongodb binary package by following the steps at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/ I'm on debian linux(Ubuntu 12.04) when I try to launch mongod, I get the message

`bash: /usr/local/bin/mongod: cannot execute binary file`

the ldd from /usr/local/bin/mongod reads
`not a dynamic executable`

Comment: `sudo service mongodb start`? But you don't neeed to launch mongodb, its service script does that

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/local/bin/mongod` and `/usr/local/bin/mongod -vvvv`?

Comment: Use the Ubuntu provided `mongodb` package.

Answer (score 4):

Installing mongodb binary package on linux takes only a few minutes.
I would like to include installation of mongodb binary steps in shorter here:

**Step 1**: Download the latest .tar.gz file from [here](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads),always prefer 64 bit for production.

**Step 2**: Make a source directory(/usr/local) and now extract the downloaded file using the below command:

```
 tar zxf mongodb-linux-i686-1.6.0.tar.gz
```

**Step 3**: Create a data directory using the below command

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

**Step 4**: Create an user mongo_user using the following command

```
useradd mongo_user
```

**Step 5**: Change the ownership of the files in the source and data directory using the following command

```
chown -R mongo_user.mongo_user /usr/local/

chown -R mongo_user.mongo_user /data/db/
```

**Step 6**: Create a configuration file in any directory say **vim /etc/mongod.conf**

Now add the following details as shown below:

```
verbose = true
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /var/log/mongodb.log
logappend = true
port = 27017
```

**Step 7**: Move to the bin folder in the source directory and now start the mongo server by the following command

```
./mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

**Step 8**: Within the bin folder in source directory start the mongo client by the following command

```
./mongo --port 27017
```

The mongodb prompt appears !!!

**P.S**: This is partially adapted from my blog. For a clearer explanation see the original [article](http://jerwinroy.blogspot.in/2015/02/mongodb.html).

Comment: mkdir -p /data/db

Comment: Thanks for the correction @aminarghavani i have made the change.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you up and running quickly:

**Install** (/home/username/)

```
sudo wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7.tgz?_ga=1.57038442.1512045927.1417277541

sudo tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7.tgz?_ga=1.57038442.1512045927.1417277541

sudo mv mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.7 mongo-2.6.7
```

**Create database directory** (/home/username/mongo-2.6.7)

```
sudo mkdir databases
```

**Start mongo**

```
mongod --dbpath /home/username/mongo-2.6.7/databases
```

**Enter shell** (/home/username/mongo-2.6.7/bin)

```
./mongo
```

You can set-up more in-depth configurations after you've played with it a bit.

Comment: This start mongo code is working from. i had problem over there.Thanks buddy.

Answer (score -1):

It is caused by running 64-bit application on 32-bit system or vice versa.

Double checkin and aligning your Linux OS version and the Mongodb version will solve this issue.